# What is the number of zeros of antiderivatives of $(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^3(x-4)^4$?

Tags: integration, roots

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^3(x-4)^4$. This
defines a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. There is a unique natural number $k$ such that every antiderivative of $f$ has either $k$ zeros or $k+2$ zeros. The natural $k$ equals to?

Comment: There was a problem with unicode characters in your function. I edited the question. Please confirm that the question you wanted to ask is the one that is there now.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but $f(x)$ has even degree, so every antiderivative has odd degree, and thus we can translate it upwards until it has only a single real zero. It follows that $k$ must be $1$. So the problem is now to show that every antiderivative has either $1$ or $3$ zeros. But if there is an antiderivative that has $3$ real zeros, then we can translate it up or down to an antiderivative that has exactly $2$ real zeros. So the problem is really asking us to show that every antiderivative of $f$ has only $1$ real zero, but this is clearly false, looking at the graph.

Comment: I didn't understood what that imply.Please write in detail.

Comment: I am implying that the question is flawed, because an antiderivative of $f$ may have $1$, $2$, or $3$ zeros.